# Generating C code from script: how to template?

Tags: python, c, templates, code-generation

I'm looking for a way to insert some auto-generated code into C source files.  The code generation is in python and that's not a problem, the trick is how to replace/update blocks of code in existing C code with the generated code.  I'm looking for a templating library which is compatible with C syntax (the templating statements can be hidden in comments), and in which the template and expanded template can be one and the same thing.

Example C file with code to be updated:

```
// start generated block (blockname)
... some code here
// end generated block (blockname)
```

Example python pseudo code:

```
replace_code_in_c_file(filename, blockname, new_code)
```

After running this the // comments stay in place but the code block would be replaced with the new code.

Comment: Why not enlist cpp to do it?

Comment: There is Cog in Python (http://nedbatchelder.com/code/cog/). But why not generate a file that you then would `#include` into your main code?

Comment: @michaelmeyer: Cog sounds very close to what I was looking for.  Post as an answer?  as for #include, I guess it depends on how many code snippets there are :)  I wanted the result to be a single C file that can be read straight through, partly for maintainability and partly for aesthetics.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: how would you use cpp?  #define stuff in one place and then let it be expanded in another place?  #include?

Comment: I'd have Python generate C code containing defines and invoke cpp with it prepended.

Comment: @Alex: if the "some code" contains preprocessor directives, the #define scheme doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex:  why is this hard to implement yourself?  Slurp in the C source file as  string.  Implement your function by finding your markers with a string search. Hack in the replacement string. Write the file content. This should be 10-20 lines of code.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain a trick. [Jinja2](https://jinja2docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a template script that can generate text from templates. What you need to do is write your C code template *main.c.j2*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

    printf("hello {{name}}.\n");

    return 0;

}
```

then you can transform it into C code with the *trans.py*:

```py
import os

from jinja2 import PackageLoader, Environment, FileSystemLoader



TemplateLoader = FileSystemLoader(os.path.abspath("."))

env = Environment(loader = TemplateLoader)



template = env.get_template("main.c.j2")



print(template.render(name = "Jack"))
```

run *python trans.py* and you will see this C code on screen:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

    printf("hello Jack.\n");

    return 0;

}
```

That's real C code, *{{name}}* is replaced into **Jack**. See the Jinja2 doc for more interesting features.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with the [re library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) in Python.

Search for the blockname and replace it with the new block:

```
re.sub(f"// start generated block \({blockname}\).*// end generated block \({blockname}\)", new_code, fileContents, flags=re.DOTALL)
```